# Trying to show changes with mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a database that stores all known data on a certain ship. Sometimes a ship is sold from one company to another. I want to relate the year/date of the sale to the company, so that if I query a ship's name and a year, it will show the company that the ship was owned by in that year; but I don't know how to relate two feilds to each other. Is there a way to do this?

I didn't try anything; I'm a novice in mysql, and am sort of trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Can you update your question and share  some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Where will you get your raw data?  Ship registration is frequently with the country of fabrication - also known as FLAG STATE.  Do you have time to gather data from more than 50 sources of information?

Comment: A sale is a transaction - doesn't make any diference if it's for ships or widgets--create a transaction table to log the sale.